# What am I? Newsletter riddle

Tags: riddle

> "I often start as an idea and then become a problem solved. There are many of me now but only the most unique and useful of my kind are lucrative."

Edit: Answer was:

> App

Comment: The quotes imply that you got this from somewhere else, can you please state your source (to avoid plagiarism).

Comment: It was from my workplace newsletter, where one of our colleagues types a a riddle every newsletter with a voucher prize. The answer she was looking for was solved by another colleague.

Answer (score 1):

> You are a startup.

Explanation:

I often start as an idea and then become a problem solved

> A startup generally starts with a vague idea to approach a problem, and if it works out successfully, it solves a problem as expected.

There are many of me now but only the most unique and useful of my kind are lucrative

> There are a lot of startups throughout the world. But only the unique or useful ones will prevail, rest will perish (Darwin everywhere!)

Answer (score 1):

> You are Software

Explanation:

I often start as an idea and then become a problem solved

> very popular softwares start with an idea like facebook website, microsoft windows,
>  Android etc. softwares usually solve many human problems example Artificial inteligence softwares, calculators etc.

There are many of me now but only the most unique and useful of my kind are lucrative

> You can find many softwares but only some are popular and earning huge
>  profit like Android, iOS, oracle etc

Answer (score 0):

You are:

> Books.

"I often start as an idea and then become a problem solved."

> I think of something and then write it up - it gets published.

"There are many of me now but only the most unique and useful of my kind are lucrative."

> Lots of books, some mediocre, some brilliant!